# Linux Ajax (mootools Request.JSON) Header error

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, mootools

I use the following code to get some json data:

```
var request = new Request.JSON(
    {
        'url':        sourceURI,
        'onSuccess':  onPageData
    }
);
request.get();
```

Request.JSON is a class from Mootools (a javascript library).

But on linux (ubuntu on firefox 3.5 and Chrome) the request always fails. So i tried to display the http request ajax is sending.
(I used netcat to display it)

The request is like this:

```
OPTIONS /the+url HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.226.0 Safari/532.3
Referer: http://example.com/ref...
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Request, X-Requested-With, Accept
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

The HTTP request (first line) is not how it should be:

```
OPTIONS /the+url HTTP/1.1
```

It should be:

```
GET /the+url HTTP/1.1
```

Does anybody know why this problem is and how to fix it?

Edit:

The ajax request gets the following result from my Apache server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2010 08:09:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Debian)
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The content-length should not be zero. But i think, the Request.JSON module whould now see that the GET request is available and can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have to do with the [W3C Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight0) spec.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks! In apache i enabled the mod_headers and added a config file in conf.d wich says:  Header set Access-Control-Access-Origin "*"  This line accept all request from all domains (somethink like the crossdomain.xml for flash).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the request header would change, but the Request classes offer more functionality to send a request. Try send() instead of get();

```
var req = neq Request.JSON({...});
req.send({
    'method': 'get'
});
```

Or bind it to the Request at once;

```
var req = new Request.JSON({
    method: 'get',
    ...
}).send();
```